# PHP date before a specified time

Tags: php

I know this has been asked in different ways but I'm struggling to get this to work.

I have a timestamp output from an API call in the following format:

**2019-12-02T14:30:00**

I'm capturing that in my PHP as follows

```
$person['StartDateTime']
```

I'm then formatting the timestamp and storing it into the $thetime variable like below.

```
$thetime = date("g.i",strtotime(date( $person['StartDateTime'])));
```

The echoed output of the $thetime to the browser gives me **14.00**

Now I want to only have the if statement work if the $thetime holds a time before 14:00, if I try the following it does not work, I just get all of the times before and after.

```
if(strtotime($thetime) < strtotime('14') ) {
//shows all times before and after, no good...
}
```

if I do the following this works...

```
if(strtotime($thetime) < strtotime('now') ) {
//shows all times before 'now' but not what I want...
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try this: if(strtotime($thetime) < date(”H”)){
}

Comment: That seems to be only saying, if the time is before the 24 hour format that doesn't actually do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by formatting the date correctly first...

```
$starttime = date("H.i",strtotime(date($thetime)));

if(strtotime($thetime) < strtotime('14') ) {
//Will now only display times before 14 (2pm)
}
```